# Official Windows C/C++ Compiler and C Libraries

Tags: c++, c, windows

I've been coding C/C++ in a Linux environment, and that has been a breeze (Open terminal > Vim > code > gcc > done). I'm trying to get into doing the same in Windows, and it hasn't been nearly as easy. I've gotten Vim to run out of terminal, as I do not like IDEs, thus I'm looking for a Windows compiler that I can work with via command-line.

My problem is that I can't find the official Windows compiler for C/C++, Microsoft support was useless, and MSDN keeps pointing me to Visual Studio. There are a plethora of questions here on SO, and the web about compilers for C/C++ on Windows, with suggestions like Dev-C++, but that comes with GCC. Visual Studio supports C/C++, and I would assume that compiler is the official one, but I've had no luck in finding just the compiler. The closest I've gotten is either the Windows SDK or Visual Studio Express 2015.

Additionally, I was told in the Stackoverflow C chat room, that C is no longer a subset of C++, so does that mean I need to find 2 compilers, one for C and one for C++?

I'm also trying to figure out where C/C++ libraries are. On Linux, they're already there. Is that the case with Windows, if not where do I find their C/C++ libraries?

I didn't expect it to be so difficult to get started, nor did I expect to get lost so quickly.

Comment: Use http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/

Comment: If by 'C/C++ libraries' you mean runtime, than it comes with Visual Studio. If you do not like Visual Studio IDE, you can use the compiler without it, there is absolutely no problem here. However, neglecting readily available IDE is a strange choice. I pity the fact that there is no IDE of comparable quality on Linux. Both gcc and clang work on Windows, btw.

Comment: you should install Visual Studio and then use Developer Command Prompt tools

Comment: @SergeyA Where can I find the compiler? I've been all over Windows/Microsoft sites and can't find it.

Comment: Try [mingw](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/), with [git bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/)

Comment: C/C++ is not a language.  There are two distinct languages, C and C++, with compatively large overlap.  This is actually important in this context, because although Microsoft provides a C++ compiler (Microsoft Visual C++, integrated into Visual Studio), the C compiler it provides is *non conforming* (but much better in recent releases than it used to be).  To my knowledge, standard C has *never* been a subset of standard C++.

Comment: @Ungeheuer, download it for free. It comes with Visual Studio Community Edition.

Comment: also if you really like how things done in linux you can checkout cygwin and mingw. also there is Visual Studio Code that is not an IDE but full featured Code Editor much of course better than VIM .

Comment: Install Visual Studio. The compiler is c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe

Comment: The compiler comes with Visual Studio.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compile-a-c-program-on-the-command-line.

Comment: Why you don't want to use a GCC port (something like MinGW-w64)? Visual Studio might be a nice IDE, but the compiler that comes with it seems (to me) inferior to GCC.

Comment: About libraries: Unless you get a linux terminal emulator that comes with package manager (like msys2), you'll have to download and compile them manually.

Comment: There is no single "official" compiler for Windows.  Several different companies produce C/C++ compilers for Windows, not just Microsoft.  For example, Embarcadero has a [free stand-alone 32bit C++11 compiler](https://www.embarcadero.com/free-tools/ccompiler) for Windows.

Comment: What @JohnBollinger said. Plus, if you want a comfortable environment, try [MSYS2](http://www.msys2.org/). It comes with a package manager (`pacman`) and you can install/use `gcc`/mingw and `clang`. Forget about the "*official*" compiler, at least for C. The only downside is that you have to stick with the ages-old `msvcrt.dll` for the standard library, only conforming to C89. But the compilers are modern (C11).

Comment: Using Visual Studio Express 14.0 (2015) on Windows 7, from the console I use `NMAKE`. I run a batch file which first calls `vcvarsall.bat` (with its whole path) then adds the location of `NMAKE.EXE` to the `PATH` environment variable, before running `NMAKE.EXE`. Of course, there must be a `MAKEFILE`.

Comment: Not sure how this is off topic...I'm not asking for a recommendation, I'm asking how to get a Windows compiler produced by Microsoft...

Comment: The same way I did: by exploring their website.

Comment: @WeatherVane I explored it to. I read tons of VS material, contacted Microsoft VS support, went through MSDN, and read a half dozen or more SO questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly enough, I found an answer to the OP's question which I believe warrants a post rather than a comment.

Microsoft does provide a stand-alone Visual C++ compiler in what they call 'build-tools'. You can get one here:

https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017-rc

(Look for Build Tools at the bottom of the page)

Comment: Please please please don't post a link that will auto-download something

Comment: @PasserBy, point taken.

Answer (score 3):

First of all there is no "official" compiler for Windows; the fact that Microsoft produce both development tools and operating-systems is a historical coincidence I won't go into.  There would be all sorts of anti-trust issues if they tried you to force you to use only their tools.  There is an official Windows SDK; and that is only available with Microsoft tools; but that too is not a barrier to Windows API development using other tools.

Visual Studio is the name of Microsoft's IDE that supports a number of development tools and languages.  The C++ compiler component of Visual Studio also supports C compilation (in common with more-or-less all C++ toolchains - that's why you often see the much hated on SO term C/C++ - because most often the toolchain is a C and C++ toolchain - not because there is a language of that name).  The fact that C is no longer an exact subset of C++ is not really an issue.

All compilers, regardless of whether or not they come embedded in some IDE have a command line interface.  Microsoft fully document theirs, so I am not sure why you could not find it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx.

To get Microsoft's tools you have to install one edition or another of Visual Studio, but you do not need to use Visual Studio to drive the compiler.  However perhaps the most compelling reason to use Visual Studio is its debugger - by far the best debugger available for any platform (IMO).  There is a command-line debugger [CDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-using-cdb-and-ntsd), but unless you love whipping yourself with birch twigs or using GDB (much the same thing), then you'll hate it.

Microsoft have long concentrated on C++, and for a long time C was left at the ISO C90 level of compliance; this has changed somewhat in more recent releases and while 2015 is improved, you would do better to use Visual Studio 2017.  There is no longer an express edition of Visual Studio, it has been replaced with the "Community Edition" with slightly less permissive licensing.  https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

All that said, you do not *have* to use Microsoft's compiler to write Windows applications in C.  MinGW (http://www.mingw.org/) is a native Windows GCC based toolchain that instead of using the POSIX dependent GNU C library, uses Microsoft's C runtime (via the DLL's included with Windows), and includes the necessary header files and export libraries to access the Windows API DLLs too.  Since Microsoft no longer licence the official Windows SDK (and the open-source MinGW could hardly use it in any case), the MinGW Windows SDK headers used to lag somewhat, but since Microsoft have more-or-less abandoned the Windows C API in favour of .NET, the API is more or less fossilised.

The advantage of MinGW is that it is the same GNU toolchain you are used to, and includes all expected GNU utilities such as make, gdb and binutils.  It even includes a bash-like shell MSYS (which you do not have to use, but makes porting, configuring and building some open-source projects easier).

Like Visual Studio, Dev-C++ is not a compiler or toolchain.  It is an IDE. It typically uses MinGW as its toolchain.  The same goes for Code::Blocks for example.

One issue with using the command line in Windows for development is that it is not as complete or fully functional a shell as say bash for example.  You may get frustrated with it is you are a bask power-user.

Comment: I've been working with PowerShell, which is so much better than cmd. GDB has always been a pain, not sure why my professor loves it so much...Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is included with Visual Studio.  It is called "cl" and can be run from the command line. See these links for instructions:

- [Walkthrough: Compiling a Native C++ Program on the Command Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compiling-a-native-cpp-program-on-the-command-line)
- [Walkthrough: Compile a C program on the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-compile-a-c-program-on-the-command-line)

They basically amount to "Open terminal > notepad > code > cl > done".  Not as hard as you're making it out to be.  I believe the instructions in those links also apply to the stand-alone build tools mentioned by the other answer.

There are better editors than notepad, and alternative compilers, but the question wasn't about editors, and cl is as close to an "official" compiler as you're going to get, so we won't get into that here.